# Multiple readers for InputStream in Java

Tags: java, io, inputstream

I have an InputStream from which I'm reading characters. I would like multiple readers to access this InputStream. It seems that a reasonable way to achieve this is to write incoming data to a StringBuffer or StringBuilder, and have the multiple readers read that. Unfortunately, StringBufferInputStream is deprecated. StringReader reads a string, not a mutable object that's continuously being updated. What are my options? Write my own?

Comment: I think you should ask yourself why you want to do this.  I have a model like this but the single reader reads the data and passes that data to where it needs to go.

Comment: I could do that, sure. The InputStream is from a Process. I'd like to log the output of the process to a file, and display it on a console in a GUI. I could read the output, and send the text to the log and the GUI, but it would be easier if there were a cached input stream or something.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: I see a scenario for this - when the different readers are independent. Example: Wrapping a console/terminal. One Reader always passes the content to be shown to the user. Another reader reacts to commands by parsing the response and eventually gives the user a different feedback based on the same input. Both readers are completely independent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Input stream work like this: once you read a portion from it, it's gone forever. You can't go back and re-read it. what you could do is something like this:

```
class InputStreamSplitter {
  InputStreamSplitter(InputStream toReadFrom) {
    this.reader = new InputStreamReader(toReadFrom);
  }
  void addListener(Listener l) {
    this.listeners.add(l);
  }
  void work() {
    String line = this.reader.readLine();
        while(line != null) {
      for(Listener l : this.listeners) {
        l.processLine(line);
      }
    }
  }
}

interface Listener {
  processLine(String line);
}
```

have all interested parties implement Listener and add them to InputStreamSplitter

Comment: "Input stream work like this: once you read a portion from it, it's gone forever. " <--- that's not entirely true.  Any InputStream implementation whose markSupported() method returns true can use mark() and reset() to effectively replay the InputStream... at least according to the contract of InputStream.

Answer (score 18):

**Note:** [My other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30262036/276052) is more general (and better in my opinion).

As noted by [@dimo414](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113632), the answer below requires the first reader to always be ahead of the second reader. If this is indeed the case for you, then this answer might still be preferable since it builds upon standard classes.

---

To create two readers that read independently from the same source, you'll have to make sure they don't consume data from the same stream.

This can be achieved by combining [`TeeInputStream`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/input/TeeInputStream.html) from Apache Commons and a [`PipedInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html) and [`PipedOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PipedOutputStream.html) as follows:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.commons.io.input.TeeInputStream;
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // Create the source input stream.
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream("filename.txt");

        // Create a piped input stream for one of the readers.
        PipedInputStream in = new PipedInputStream();

        // Create a tee-splitter for the other reader.
        TeeInputStream tee = new TeeInputStream(is, new PipedOutputStream(in));

        // Create the two buffered readers.
        BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(tee));
        BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Do some interleaved reads from them.
        System.out.println("One line from br1:");
        System.out.println(br1.readLine());
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Two lines from br2:");
        System.out.println(br2.readLine());
        System.out.println(br2.readLine());
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("One line from br1:");
        System.out.println(br1.readLine());
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
One line from br1:
Line1: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,      <-- reading from start

Two lines from br2:
Line1: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,      <-- reading from start
Line2: consectetur adipisicing elit,

One line from br1:
Line2: consectetur adipisicing elit,    <-- resumes on line 2
```

Comment: Be aware by copy pasting this code. This works not in any case. For example if the InputStream comes from `ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("myResource")` it will get stuck.

Comment: This pattern can cause your program to unexpectedly block.  `br2` is only able to read past `br1` because `br1`'s buffer is long enough to fit both lines.  If you comment out the first `br1.readLine()` the program hangs.

Comment: @dimo414, thanks for catching this. Added a big discramer at the top, and wrote a proper answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034311/multiple-readers-for-inputstream-in-java/30262036#30262036). Feedback on my new answer is most welcome.

Answer (score 11):

As you've probably noted, once you've read a byte from an input stream, it's gone forever (unless you've saved it somewhere yourself).

The solution below does save the bytes until *all* subscribing input streams have read it.

It works as follows:

```
// Create a SplittableInputStream from the originalStream
SplittableInputStream is  = new SplittableInputStream(originalStream);

// Fork this to get more input streams reading independently from originalStream
SplittableInputStream is2 = is.split();
SplittableInputStream is3 = is.split();
```

Each time `is` is `split()` it will yield a new `InputStream` that will read the bytes from the point where `is` was split.

The `SplittableInputStream` looks as follows (copy'n'paste away!):

```
class SplittableInputStream extends InputStream {

    // Almost an input stream: The read-method takes an id.
    static class MultiplexedSource {

        static int MIN_BUF = 4096;

        // Underlying source
        private InputStream source;

        // Read positions of each SplittableInputStream
        private List<Integer> readPositions = new ArrayList<>();

        // Data to be read by the SplittableInputStreams
        int[] buffer = new int[MIN_BUF];

        // Last valid position in buffer
        int writePosition = 0;

        public MultiplexedSource(InputStream source) {
            this.source = source;
        }

        // Add a multiplexed reader. Return new reader id.
        int addSource(int splitId) {
            readPositions.add(splitId == -1 ? 0 : readPositions.get(splitId));
            return readPositions.size() - 1;
        }

        // Make room for more data (and drop data that has been read by
        // all readers)
        private void readjustBuffer() {
            int from = Collections.min(readPositions);
            int to = Collections.max(readPositions);
            int newLength = Math.max((to - from) * 2, MIN_BUF);
            int[] newBuf = new int[newLength];
            System.arraycopy(buffer, from, newBuf, 0, to - from);
            for (int i = 0; i < readPositions.size(); i++)
                readPositions.set(i, readPositions.get(i) - from);
            writePosition -= from;
            buffer = newBuf;
        }

        // Read and advance position for given reader
        public int read(int readerId) throws IOException {

            // Enough data in buffer?
            if (readPositions.get(readerId) >= writePosition) {
                readjustBuffer();
                buffer[writePosition++] = source.read();
            }

            int pos = readPositions.get(readerId);
            int b = buffer[pos];
            if (b != -1)
                readPositions.set(readerId, pos + 1);
            return b;
        }
    }

    // Non-root fields
    MultiplexedSource multiSource;
    int myId;

    // Public constructor: Used for first SplittableInputStream
    public SplittableInputStream(InputStream source) {
        multiSource = new MultiplexedSource(source);
        myId = multiSource.addSource(-1);
    }

    // Private constructor: Used in split()
    private SplittableInputStream(MultiplexedSource multiSource, int splitId) {
        this.multiSource = multiSource;
        myId = multiSource.addSource(splitId);
    }

    // Returns a new InputStream that will read bytes from this position
    // onwards.
    public SplittableInputStream split() {
        return new SplittableInputStream(multiSource, myId);
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        return multiSource.read(myId);
    }
}
```

Finally, a demo:

```
String str = "Lorem ipsum\ndolor sit\namet\n";
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes("UTF-8"));

// Create the two buffered readers.
SplittableInputStream is1 = new SplittableInputStream(is);
SplittableInputStream is2 = is1.split();

BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is1));
BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is2));

// Do some interleaved reads from them.
System.out.println("One line from br1:");
System.out.println(br1.readLine());
System.out.println();

System.out.println("Two lines from br2:");
System.out.println(br2.readLine());
System.out.println(br2.readLine());
System.out.println();

System.out.println("One line from br1:");
System.out.println(br1.readLine());
System.out.println();
```

**Output:**

```
One line from br1:
Lorem ipsum

Two lines from br2:
Lorem ipsum
dolor sit

One line from br1:
dolor sit
```

Comment: Cool, looks like it works!  Could use 4 times less buffer space and overload `read(byte[], int, int)` for better efficiency, but that's an "exercise for the reader".  It would be clearer though to just say `int to = writePosition;` in `readjustBuffer`.

Comment: If you have one reader, then readjustBuffer will be called for every byte read, which will hurt perfomane since you have to copy 4K with bytes for every byte read..

Answer (score 8):

Use [TeeInputStream](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/input/TeeInputStream.html) to copy all the bytes read from `InputStream` to secondary `OutputStream`, e.g. `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using StringWriter/StringBufferInputStream, write your original InputStream to a ByteArrayOutputStream.  Once you've finished reading from the original InputStream, pass the byte array returned from ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray to a ByteArrayInputStream.  Use this InputStream as the InputStream of choice for passing around other things that need to read from it.

Essentially, all you'd be doing here is storing the contents of the original InputStream into a byte[] cache in memory as you tried to do originally with StringWriter/StringBufferInputStream.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to read from two streams independently, without presuming one is ahead of the other, but with standard classes. It does, however, eagerly read from the underlying input stream in the background, which may be undesirable, depending on your application.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  // Create the source input stream.
  InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream("line1\nline2\nline3".getBytes());

  // Create a piped input stream for each reader;
  PipedInputStream in1 = new PipedInputStream();
  PipedInputStream in2 = new PipedInputStream();

  // Start copying the input stream to both piped input streams.
  startCopy(is, new TeeOutputStream(
      new PipedOutputStream(in1), new PipedOutputStream(in2)));

  // Create the two buffered readers.
  BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in1));
  BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in2));

  // Do some interleaved reads from them.
  // ...
}

private static void startCopy(InputStream in, OutputStream out) {
  (new Thread() {
    public void run() {
      try {
        IOUtils.copy(in, out);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    }
  }).start();
}
```

Comment: The parameters of startCopy need to be final

Comment: As of Java 8, they don't need to be final, but yes prior to Java 8, they do.

Comment: "... but with standard classes" - well, not quite "standard classes". TeeOutputStream is from an Apache dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for a possible way to have an outputstream sending bytes to two or more different Inputstream, I found this forum.
Unfortunately, the exact solution was directing to PipedOutputStream and PipedInputStream. 
So, I was declined to write a PipeOutputStream extension.
Here it is. The example is written in the PipedOutputStream's "main" method.

```
/**
 * Extensao de {@link PipedOutputStream}, onde eh possivel conectar mais de um {@link PipedInputStream}
 */
public class PipedOutputStreamEx extends PipedOutputStream {

    /**
     * 
     */
    public PipedOutputStreamEx() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /* REMIND: identification of the read and write sides needs to be
       more sophisticated.  Either using thread groups (but what about
       pipes within a thread?) or using finalization (but it may be a
       long time until the next GC). */
    private PipedInputStreamEx[] sinks=null;

    public synchronized void connect(PipedInputStreamEx... pIns) throws IOException {
        for (PipedInputStreamEx snk : pIns) {
            if (snk == null) {
                throw new NullPointerException();
            } else if (sinks != null || snk.connected) {
                throw new IOException("Already connected");
            }
            snk.in = -1;
            snk.out = 0;
            snk.connected = true;
        }

        this.sinks = pIns;
    }


    /**
     * Writes the specified <code>byte</code> to the piped output stream. 
     * <p>
     * Implements the <code>write</code> method of <code>OutputStream</code>.
     *
     * @param      b   the <code>byte</code> to be written.
     * @exception IOException if the pipe is <a href=#BROKEN> broken</a>,
     *      {@link #connect(java.io.PipedInputStream) unconnected},
     *      closed, or if an I/O error occurs.
     */
    public void write(int b)  throws IOException {
        if (this.sinks == null) {
            throw new IOException("Pipe(s) not connected");
        }
        for (PipedInputStreamEx sink : this.sinks) {
            sink.receive(b);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Writes <code>len</code> bytes from the specified byte array 
     * starting at offset <code>off</code> to this piped output stream. 
     * This method blocks until all the bytes are written to the output
     * stream.
     *
     * @param      b     the data.
     * @param      off   the start offset in the data.
     * @param      len   the number of bytes to write.
     * @exception IOException if the pipe is <a href=#BROKEN> broken</a>,
     *          {@link #connect(java.io.PipedInputStream) unconnected},
     *      closed, or if an I/O error occurs.
     */
    public void write(byte b[], int off, int len) throws IOException {
        if (sinks == null) {
            throw new IOException("Pipe not connected");
        } else if (b == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        } else if ((off < 0) || (off > b.length) || (len < 0) ||
                ((off + len) > b.length) || ((off + len) < 0)) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        } else if (len == 0) {
            return;
        } 
        for (PipedInputStreamEx sink : this.sinks) {
            sink.receive(b, off, len);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Flushes this output stream and forces any buffered output bytes 
     * to be written out. 
     * This will notify any readers that bytes are waiting in the pipe.
     *
     * @exception IOException if an I/O error occurs.
     */
    public synchronized void flush() throws IOException {
        if (sinks != null) {
            for (PipedInputStreamEx sink : this.sinks) {
                synchronized (sink) {
                    sink.notifyAll();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Closes this piped output stream and releases any system resources 
     * associated with this stream. This stream may no longer be used for 
     * writing bytes.
     *
     * @exception  IOException  if an I/O error occurs.
     */
    public void close()  throws IOException {
        if (sinks != null) {
            for (PipedInputStreamEx sink : this.sinks) {
                sink.receivedLast();
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * Teste desta extensao de {@link PipedOutputStream}
     * @param args
     * @throws InterruptedException 
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        final PipedOutputStreamEx pOut = new PipedOutputStreamEx();
        final PipedInputStreamEx pInHash = new PipedInputStreamEx();
        final PipedInputStreamEx pInConsole = new PipedInputStreamEx();

        pOut.connect(pInHash, pInConsole);

        Thread escreve = new Thread("Escrevendo") {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String[] paraGravar = new String[]{
                        "linha1 0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789\n"
                        , "linha2 0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789\n"
                        , "linha3 0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789\n"
                        , "linha4 0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789\n"
                        , "linha5 0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789\n"
                        , "linha6 0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789\n"
                        , "linha7 0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789\n"
                        , "linha8 0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789\n"
                        , "linha9 0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789\n"
                        , "linha10 0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789\n"
                        , "linha11 0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789\n"
                        , "linha12 0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789\n"
                        , "linha13 0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789\n"
                        , "linha14 0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789\n"
                        , "linha15 0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789\n"
                        , "linha16 0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789\n"
                        , "linha17 0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789\n"
                        , "linha18 0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789\n"
                        , "linha19 0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789\n"
                        , "linha20 0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789\n"
                };
                for (String s :paraGravar) {
                    try {
                        pOut.write(s.getBytes("ISO-8859-1") );
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
                try {
                    pOut.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }   
        };

        Thread le1 = new Thread("Le1 - hash") {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    System.out.println("HASH: "+HashUtil.getHashCRC(pInHash,true));                         
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        Thread le2 = new Thread("Le2 - escreve no console") {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                BufferedReader bIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pInConsole));
                String s;
                try {
                    while ( (s=bIn.readLine())!=null) {
                        Thread.sleep(700); //teste simulando o um leitor lento...
                        System.out.println(s);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };


        escreve.start();
        le1.start();
        le2.start();

        escreve.join();
        le1.join();
        le2.join();

        pInHash.close();
        pInConsole.close();
    }
}
```

Here is the PipedInputStreamEx code. Unfortunately, I had to copy all JDK code, to have access to "connected", "in" and "out" properties.

```
/**
 * Extensao de {@link PipedInputStream}, que permite conetar mais de um destes no {@link PipedOutputStream}
 * Como a classe ancestral possui propriedades 'package friend', tivemos que copiar o codigo herdado :/
 */
public class PipedInputStreamEx extends PipedInputStream {

    @Override
    public void connect(PipedOutputStream src) throws IOException {
        throw new IOException("conecte usando PipedOutputStream.connect()");
    }

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--------- INICIO codigo da classe herdada (alguns metodos comentados...)----------------------------------
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    boolean closedByWriter = false;
    volatile boolean closedByReader = false;
    boolean connected = false;

    /* REMIND: identification of the read and write sides needs to be
       more sophisticated.  Either using thread groups (but what about
       pipes within a thread?) or using finalization (but it may be a
       long time until the next GC). */
    Thread readSide;
    Thread writeSide;

    private static final int DEFAULT_PIPE_SIZE = 1024;

    /**
     * The default size of the pipe's circular input buffer.
     * @since   JDK1.1
     */
    // This used to be a constant before the pipe size was allowed
    // to change. This field will continue to be maintained
    // for backward compatibility. 
    protected static final int PIPE_SIZE = DEFAULT_PIPE_SIZE;

    /**
     * The circular buffer into which incoming data is placed.
     * @since   JDK1.1
     */
    protected byte buffer[];

    /**
     * The index of the position in the circular buffer at which the
     * next byte of data will be stored when received from the connected
     * piped output stream. <code>in&lt;0</code> implies the buffer is empty,
     * <code>in==out</code> implies the buffer is full
     * @since   JDK1.1
     */
    protected int in = -1;

    /**
     * The index of the position in the circular buffer at which the next
     * byte of data will be read by this piped input stream.
     * @since   JDK1.1
     */
    protected int out = 0;

//    /**
//     * Creates a <code>PipedInputStream</code> so
//     * that it is connected to the piped output
//     * stream <code>src</code>. Data bytes written
//     * to <code>src</code> will then be  available
//     * as input from this stream.
//     *
//     * @param      src   the stream to connect to.
//     * @exception  IOException  if an I/O error occurs.
//     */
//    public PipedInputStream(PipedOutputStream src) throws IOException {
//        this(src, DEFAULT_PIPE_SIZE);
//    }
//
//    /**
//     * Creates a <code>PipedInputStream</code> so that it is
//     * connected to the piped output stream
//     * <code>src</code> and uses the specified pipe size for
//     * the pipe's buffer.
//     * Data bytes written to <code>src</code> will then
//     * be available as input from this stream.
//     *
//     * @param      src   the stream to connect to.
//     * @param      pipeSize the size of the pipe's buffer.
//     * @exception  IOException  if an I/O error occurs.
//     * @exception  IllegalArgumentException if <code>pipeSize <= 0</code>.
//     * @since    1.6
//     */
//    public PipedInputStream(PipedOutputStream src, int pipeSize)
//            throws IOException {
//   initPipe(pipeSize);
//   connect(src);
//    }

    /**
     * Creates a <code>PipedInputStream</code> so
     * that it is not yet {@linkplain #connect(java.io.PipedOutputStream)
     * connected}.
     * It must be {@linkplain java.io.PipedOutputStream#connect(
     * java.io.PipedInputStream) connected} to a
     * <code>PipedOutputStream</code> before being used.
     */
    public PipedInputStreamEx() {
    initPipe(DEFAULT_PIPE_SIZE);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a <code>PipedInputStream</code> so that it is not yet
     * {@linkplain #connect(java.io.PipedOutputStream) connected} and
     * uses the specified pipe size for the pipe's buffer.
     * It must be {@linkplain java.io.PipedOutputStream#connect(
     * java.io.PipedInputStream)
     * connected} to a <code>PipedOutputStream</code> before being used.
     *
     * @param      pipeSize the size of the pipe's buffer.
     * @exception  IllegalArgumentException if <code>pipeSize <= 0</code>.
     * @since      1.6
     */
    public PipedInputStreamEx(int pipeSize) {
    initPipe(pipeSize);
    }

    private void initPipe(int pipeSize) {
         if (pipeSize <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Pipe Size <= 0");
         }
         buffer = new byte[pipeSize];
    }

//    /**
//     * Causes this piped input stream to be connected
//     * to the piped  output stream <code>src</code>.
//     * If this object is already connected to some
//     * other piped output  stream, an <code>IOException</code>
//     * is thrown.
//     * <p>
//     * If <code>src</code> is an
//     * unconnected piped output stream and <code>snk</code>
//     * is an unconnected piped input stream, they
//     * may be connected by either the call:
//     * <p>
//     * <pre><code>snk.connect(src)</code> </pre>
//     * <p>
//     * or the call:
//     * <p>
//     * <pre><code>src.connect(snk)</code> </pre>
//     * <p>
//     * The two
//     * calls have the same effect.
//     *
//     * @param      src   The piped output stream to connect to.
//     * @exception  IOException  if an I/O error occurs.
//     */
//    public void connect(PipedOutputStream src) throws IOException {
//  src.connect(this);
//    }

    /**
     * Receives a byte of data.  This method will block if no input is
     * available.
     * @param b the byte being received
     * @exception IOException If the pipe is <a href=#BROKEN> <code>broken</code></a>,
     *      {@link #connect(java.io.PipedOutputStream) unconnected},
     *      closed, or if an I/O error occurs.
     * @since     JDK1.1
     */
    protected synchronized void receive(int b) throws IOException {
        checkStateForReceive();
        writeSide = Thread.currentThread();
        if (in == out)
            awaitSpace();
    if (in < 0) {
        in = 0;
        out = 0;
    }
    buffer[in++] = (byte)(b & 0xFF);
    if (in >= buffer.length) {
        in = 0;
    }
    }

    /**
     * Receives data into an array of bytes.  This method will
     * block until some input is available.
     * @param b the buffer into which the data is received
     * @param off the start offset of the data
     * @param len the maximum number of bytes received
     * @exception IOException If the pipe is <a href=#BROKEN> broken</a>,
     *       {@link #connect(java.io.PipedOutputStream) unconnected},
     *       closed,or if an I/O error occurs.
     */
    synchronized void receive(byte b[], int off, int len)  throws IOException {
        checkStateForReceive();
        writeSide = Thread.currentThread();
        int bytesToTransfer = len;
        while (bytesToTransfer > 0) {
            if (in == out)
                awaitSpace();
            int nextTransferAmount = 0;
            if (out < in) {
                nextTransferAmount = buffer.length - in;
            } else if (in < out) {
                if (in == -1) {
                    in = out = 0;
                    nextTransferAmount = buffer.length - in;
                } else {
                    nextTransferAmount = out - in;
                }
            }
            if (nextTransferAmount > bytesToTransfer)
                nextTransferAmount = bytesToTransfer;
            assert(nextTransferAmount > 0);
            System.arraycopy(b, off, buffer, in, nextTransferAmount);
            bytesToTransfer -= nextTransferAmount;
            off += nextTransferAmount;
            in += nextTransferAmount;
            if (in >= buffer.length) {
                in = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    private void checkStateForReceive() throws IOException {
        if (!connected) {
            throw new IOException("Pipe not connected");
        } else if (closedByWriter || closedByReader) {
        throw new IOException("Pipe closed");
    } else if (readSide != null && !readSide.isAlive()) {
            throw new IOException("Read end dead");
        }
    }

    private void awaitSpace() throws IOException {
    while (in == out) {
        checkStateForReceive();

        /* full: kick any waiting readers */
        notifyAll();
        try {
            wait(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        throw new java.io.InterruptedIOException();
        }
    }
    }

    /**
     * Notifies all waiting threads that the last byte of data has been
     * received.
     */
    synchronized void receivedLast() {
    closedByWriter = true;
    notifyAll();
    }

    /**
     * Reads the next byte of data from this piped input stream. The
     * value byte is returned as an <code>int</code> in the range
     * <code>0</code> to <code>255</code>. 
     * This method blocks until input data is available, the end of the
     * stream is detected, or an exception is thrown.
     *
     * @return     the next byte of data, or <code>-1</code> if the end of the
     *             stream is reached.
     * @exception  IOException  if the pipe is
     *       {@link #connect(java.io.PipedOutputStream) unconnected},
     *       <a href=#BROKEN> <code>broken</code></a>, closed,
     *       or if an I/O error occurs.
     */
    public synchronized int read()  throws IOException {
        if (!connected) {
            throw new IOException("Pipe not connected");
        } else if (closedByReader) {
        throw new IOException("Pipe closed");
    } else if (writeSide != null && !writeSide.isAlive()
                   && !closedByWriter && (in < 0)) {
            throw new IOException("Write end dead");
    }

        readSide = Thread.currentThread();
    int trials = 2;
    while (in < 0) {
        if (closedByWriter) {
        /* closed by writer, return EOF */
        return -1;
        }
        if ((writeSide != null) && (!writeSide.isAlive()) && (--trials < 0)) {
        throw new IOException("Pipe broken");
        }
            /* might be a writer waiting */
        notifyAll();
        try {
            wait(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        throw new java.io.InterruptedIOException();
        }
    }
    int ret = buffer[out++] & 0xFF;
    if (out >= buffer.length) {
        out = 0;
    }
    if (in == out) {
            /* now empty */
        in = -1;
    }

    return ret;
    }

    /**
     * Reads up to <code>len</code> bytes of data from this piped input
     * stream into an array of bytes. Less than <code>len</code> bytes
     * will be read if the end of the data stream is reached or if 
     * <code>len</code> exceeds the pipe's buffer size.
     * If <code>len </code> is zero, then no bytes are read and 0 is returned; 
     * otherwise, the method blocks until at least 1 byte of input is 
     * available, end of the stream has been detected, or an exception is
     * thrown.
     *
     * @param      b     the buffer into which the data is read.
     * @param      off   the start offset in the destination array <code>b</code>
     * @param      len   the maximum number of bytes read.
     * @return     the total number of bytes read into the buffer, or
     *             <code>-1</code> if there is no more data because the end of
     *             the stream has been reached.
     * @exception  NullPointerException If <code>b</code> is <code>null</code>.
     * @exception  IndexOutOfBoundsException If <code>off</code> is negative, 
     * <code>len</code> is negative, or <code>len</code> is greater than 
     * <code>b.length - off</code>
     * @exception  IOException if the pipe is <a href=#BROKEN> <code>broken</code></a>,
     *       {@link #connect(java.io.PipedOutputStream) unconnected},
     *       closed, or if an I/O error occurs.
     */
    public synchronized int read(byte b[], int off, int len)  throws IOException {
    if (b == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    } else if (off < 0 || len < 0 || len > b.length - off) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    } else if (len == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

        /* possibly wait on the first character */
    int c = read();
    if (c < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    b[off] = (byte) c;
    int rlen = 1;
    while ((in >= 0) && (len > 1)) {

        int available; 

        if (in > out) {
        available = Math.min((buffer.length - out), (in - out));
        } else {
        available = buffer.length - out;
        }

        // A byte is read beforehand outside the loop
        if (available > (len - 1)) {
        available = len - 1;
        }
        System.arraycopy(buffer, out, b, off + rlen, available);
        out += available;
        rlen += available; 
        len -= available;

        if (out >= buffer.length) {
        out = 0;
        }
        if (in == out) {
                /* now empty */
        in = -1;
        }
    }
    return rlen;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of bytes that can be read from this input
     * stream without blocking.
     *
     * @return the number of bytes that can be read from this input stream
     *         without blocking, or {@code 0} if this input stream has been
     *         closed by invoking its {@link #close()} method, or if the pipe
     *         is {@link #connect(java.io.PipedOutputStream) unconnected}, or
     *      <a href=#BROKEN> <code>broken</code></a>.
     *
     * @exception  IOException  if an I/O error occurs.
     * @since   JDK1.0.2
     */
    public synchronized int available() throws IOException {
    if(in < 0)
        return 0;
    else if(in == out)
        return buffer.length;
    else if (in > out)
        return in - out;
    else
        return in + buffer.length - out;
    }

    /**
     * Closes this piped input stream and releases any system resources
     * associated with the stream.
     *
     * @exception  IOException  if an I/O error occurs.
     */
    public void close()  throws IOException {
    closedByReader = true;
        synchronized (this) {
            in = -1;
        }
    }

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--------- FIM codigo da classe herdada -------------------------------------------------------------------
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


}
```