# CXF REST: How can I retrieve the POJO object from the message in an interceptor before it gets marshal'd?

Tags: rest, cxf, message, interceptor, pojo

We have implemented a REST API in CXF. My goal is to be able to define custom annotations on a POJO and process them in a CXF interceptor before they get marshal'd. I believe I have all the information I need to be able to do this except for retrieving the actual object in the interceptor. My code looks like this:

1. Resource class

   ```
   @Path("/mypath")
   public class MyResource {

       @GET
       public MyObject getObject() {
          MyObject o = new MyObject();
          ...
          return o;
       }
   }
   ```
2. MyObject

   ```
   public class MyObject {

       private String x;

       @MyAnnotation
       public String getX() {
          return x;
       }

       public String setX(x) {
          this.x = x;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Interceptor

   ```
   public class MyInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {

       public VersionOutInterceptor() {
           super(Phase.POST_LOGICAL);
       }

       public final void handleMessage(Message message) {
           // 1. STUCK -- get object from the message
           // 2. parse annotations and manipulate the object
           // 3. put the object back on the message for serialization
       }
   }
   ```

How do I get the object from the message, manipulate it based on the annotations, and put it back on the message?

Comment: Take a loog here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763544/how-to-deal-with-input-parameter-in-cxf-request-handler-in-general

Answer (score 9):

I have similar requirement and this is how I could do it

for In Interceptor I have used **PRE_INVOKE** Phase and for Out Interceptor **PRE_LOGICAL** Phase.
This code shows only logging but you can change the object if needed by Usecase.

code as below will fetch you the object you are looking for

```
@Override
   public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
      MessageContentsList objs = MessageContentsList.getContentsList(message);
      if (objs != null && objs.size() == 1) {
      Object responseObj = objs.get(0);
      DomainPOJO do= (DomainPOJO)responseObj;
   _logger.info(do.toString());
  }
}
```