# cxf out interceptor - reference to response pojo object

Tags: spring, cxf, interceptor

I need to get the response Java object that is returned from my service for some processing of the data. I don't want to write the code to process this data in the ServiceImpl class itself since I want to keep it configuration based. I have written the out interceptor. 
As per answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620622/cxf-rest-how-can-i-retrieve-the-pojo-object-from-the-message-in-an-interceptor)  , the POJO object should be available in the out interceptor, however I see that the object is actually an intermediate class of response. I get a ClassCastException with the code mentioned in above link.

Am I missing something? Can the same POJO object returned by Service class be available in the Out interceptor?

Any other approach to accomplish this is also welcome.

***MyOutInterceptor.java:***

```
public class MyOutInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {

public MyOutInterceptor() {
    super(Phase.MARSHAL); // Tried Phase.PRE_LOGICAL as well
}

public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
MessageContentsList objs = MessageContentsList.getContentsList(message); 
if (objs != null && objs.size() == 1) { 
    Object responseObj = objs.get(0); 
    MyData data = (MyData) responseObj; // fails here with ClassCastException
    ...
}
```

***applicationContext.xml***

```
<bean class="com.xyz.interceptor.MyOutInterceptor" id="outInterceptor" />

<jaxws:endpoint id="dataService" implementor="#masterDataService" address="/MasterDataService">
...
    <jaxws:outInterceptors>
        <ref bean="outInterceptor" />
    </jaxws:outInterceptors>
</jaxws:endpoint>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pre-logical phase will work, but you would need to do an:

addBefore(WrapperClassOutInterceptor.class.getName());

to make sure it's run before that interceptor.

Comment: Worked like a charm after the suggested change... Thank you so much