# IOUtils.copy fails 2nd time

Tags: java, servlets

I have a servlet that uses a method with the following logic:

```
        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        IOUtils.copy(content, out);
        out.close();
```

When I run through it the first time, everything works as expected.  If I attempt to do the same procedure a second time, with the same content, out is empty. I have inspected the content object while debugging the second time and it's identical to the content the first time.  Any ideas what could be happening?

Comment: After you've closed the output stream with out.close() you can't write to it anymore.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What is the type and scope of `content`? Have you drained an `InputStream`? Once it's empty, it's empty.

Comment: even though I close out, when I call the servlet again it should be recreating a new out so it should be open.  content is being written to cache on the first pass and read out of the cache on the second pass.

Comment: hmmm... does copy "drain" the original InputStream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are not trying to write to a closed output stream (which was my first guess, but your comment leads me to think that the servlet itself is re-invoked, which will open a new response), then it's likely that your input stream needs to be reset.  Depending on what kind of actual stream it is, you can either use mark and reset on the stream itself, or you can recreate the stream, or you can copy it into memory as a byte array for reuse.  See this question: [Read stream twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501237/read-stream-twice)

Comment: thanks, I think you are right about it needing to be reset.  I'm trying to avoid converting to a byte array, so I'll give reset a go.  Thanks again for the advice.  If things work out I'll be sure to accept your answer.