# Why does IOUtils.copy() works once [APACHE COMMON NET+IO]

Tags: java, apache, file, ftp, apache-commons

I got a program that needs to fetch information in different files in a FTP.

I am using Apache common net and io. As you can see down below, I usesd IOUtils.copy().
With that, I copy the content in the txt files.

```
StringWriter stringWriter_getWebVersion = new StringWriter();
IOUtils.copy(FTPManager.retrieveFileStream(root + "/Version.txt"), stringWriter_getWebVersion, "UTF-8");
string_WebVersion = stringWriter_getWebVersion.toString();

StringWriter stringWriter_getWhatsNew = new StringWriter();
IOUtils.copy(FTPManager.retrieveFileStream(root + "/New.txt"), stringWriter_getWhatsNew, "UTF-8");
string_WhatsNew = stringWriter_getWhatsNew.toString();
```

If I put only the first 3 lines (those 3 lines are required to copy the content of a file, the last 3 lines are the 2nd copy) it works correctly, but if I put the second copy, it will not work for some reason.

Here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:113)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1906)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1933)
    at ---.---.---.----.------(----.java:32) //Voir 5eme ligne du code.
    at -------(---.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

I have tried multiple things: (For testing purposes, the content of the 2 files are the same).

1st test: removing them sepretly:

- Remove the 1st copy (line 1-3): The content from New.txt is read correctly
- Remove the 2nd copy (line 4-6): The content from Version.txt is read correctly
- BUT if both are active, the content from Version.txt is read but not the second (see error from above).

Info about the FTP (Raspberry Pi):

```
logiciel (the account folder of the user (in /home for people who know Linux))
     |-> Update
           |-> MSU (Test folder)
                |-> Version.txt    (content: 1.1.0)
                |-> New.txt    (content: 1.0.0)
```

the root string: "Update/MSU"

Thanks for your help.

Note: Do not mark as dupe from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14103864/ioutils-copy-fails-2nd-time) because I am not doing it that way. (+ he is doing it on a servlet)

Comment: Did you check the FTPManager implementation ? The shown exception can come if FTPManager is unable to locate the file (when multiple files are requested)

Comment: @DevBlanked I did check and it doesn't come from there. But i'll look again.

Comment: didn't you ask the same question about 3 days ago?

Comment: @guido I did but I deleted it accidently (misclicked the edit button). So I recreated it but with much more detail and clearness.

Comment: fair enough; where does the FTPManager class come from? it doesn't seem to be in commons? i guess the static `retrieveFileStream` call is returning null the second time

Comment: @guido FTPManage is a custom class for my server connection (and it does extend from FTPClient which is from apache commons)

Comment: that's where the issue is, so that's the code you have to show

Comment: @guido I tested by directly testing from FTPClient but it didn't change anything.