# How to re-read an InputStream after calling IOUtils.copy?

Tags: java, inputstream

I simply use

```
IOUtils.copy(myInputStream, myOutputStream);
```

And I see that before calling IOUtils.copy the input stream is avaible to read and after not.

```
flux.available()
     (int) 1368181 (before)
     (int) 0 (after)
```

I saw some explanation on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501237/read-stream-twice), and I see I can copy the  `bytes` from my `InputStream` to a `ByteArrayInputStream` and then use `mark(0)` and `read()`, in order to read multiple times an input stream.

Here is the code resulted (which is working).
I find this code very verbose, and I'd like if there is a better solution to do that.

```
ByteArrayInputStream fluxResetable = new ByteArrayInputStream(IOUtils.toByteArray(myInputStream));
fluxResetable.mark(0);
IOUtils.copy(fluxResetable, myOutputStream);
fluxResetable.reset();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An `InputStream`, unless otherwise stated, is single shot: you consume it once and that's it.

If you want to read it many times, that isn't just a stream any more, it's a stream with a buffer. Your solution reflects that accurately, so it is acceptable. The one thing I would probably change is to store the byte array and always create a new `ByteArrayInputStream` from it when needed, rather than resetting the same one:

```
byte [] content = IOUtils.toByteArray(myInputStream);
IOUtils.copy(new ByteArrayInputStream(content), myOutputStream);
doSomethingElse(new ByteArrayInputStream(content));
```

The effect is more or less the same but it's slightly easier to see what you're trying to do.