# How to read a DataInputStream twice or more than twice?

Tags: java, android, sockets, datainputstream

I have a Socket connection to an application that I hosted elsewhere. Once I connected I made a `OutputStream` and `DataInputStream`.

Once the connection has been made, I use the `OutputStream` to send out a handshake packet to the application. Once this handshake has been approved, it returns a packet through the `DataInputStream` (1).

This packet is processed and is returned to the application with the `OutputStream`.

If this returned data is valid, I get another packet from the `DataInputStream` (2). However, I have not been able to read this packet through the `DataInputStream`.

I have tried to use `DataInputStream.markSupported()` and `DataInputStream.mark()` but this gave me nothing (except for an empty Exception message).

Is it possible to read the input stream for a second time? And if so, can someone please point me out what I'm doing wrong here?

EDIT: Here is my solution:

```cs
// First define the Output and Input streams.
OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream();
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

// Send the first packet to the application.
output.write("test"); // (not actual data that I sent)

// Make an empty byte array and fill it with the first response from the application.
byte[] incoming = new byte[200];
bis.read(incoming); //First packet receive

//Send a second packet to the application.
output.write("test2"); // (not actual data that I sent)

// Mark the Input stream to the length of the first response and reset the stream.
bis.mark(incoming.length);
bis.reset();

// Create a second empty byte array and fill it with the second response from the application.
byte[] incoming2 = new byte[200];
bis.read(incoming2);
```

I'm not sure if this is the most correct way to do this, but this way it worked for me.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501237/read-stream-twice

Comment: A much better solution is to remember anything you need to remember and only ever read once.

Comment: That is my problem. I don't get everything in the first read. I get a second (and third) response from the application after I submitted a packet from the `OutputStream`.

Comment: @MarcoFerrari I have added a working example with explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use ByteArrayInput stream or something that you can reset.  That would involve reading the data into another type of input stream and then creating one.

InputStream has a `markSupported()` method that you could check on the original and the byte array one to find one that the mark will work with:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#markSupported()
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html

Comment: How would I be going on to do this? From what I understand is that I need to read the line with the `InputStream` and put the result in a `ByteArrayInputStream`. However, `markSupported()` has no effect and I cannot seem to read the `InputStream` for a second time.

Comment: I seem to have it working now based upon your answer. However I did not use `ByteArrayInputStream`. I also used the regular `mark` and counted the amount of bytes I was in. And I've replaced `DataInputStream` to `BufferedInputStream`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is not re-reading the input. I don't see anything in the question that requires you to read the input twice. The problem is the `BufferedInputStream,` which will read everything that is available to be read, including the second message, if it has already arrived.

The solution is not to use a buffered stream until you have completed the handshake. Just issue a read on the socket input stream for exactly the length of the first message, do the handshake, and then proceed to construct and read the buffered stream.

Comment: The last piece of code is the solution I came up with myself (but as I said, it might not be the best way). The problem was that I could not read the `BufferedInputStream` for a second time after I sent some data over the `OutputStream`. However, this is fixed by using `mark()` and `reset()`.