# Properties not loading in java

Tags: java, properties

I have the following code

```
Properties influxProps = new Properties();
InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/influx.properties");
String result = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
System.out.println("INFLUX PROPERTIES : "+result);
influxProps.load(inputStream);
System.out.println("Properties: "+influxProps.toString());
```

I am able to fetch the file and the result also displays the contents of the file correctly.

But loading of the input stream into influx properties doesn't work.
When I try to print out the properties map it prints out nothing.

How do I resolve this. I am not running this code inside a static method.

Comment: Streams are stateful. Once you convert it to string, you're at the end of the stream, so there's nothing left to read. You'll need to open the file again.

Comment: Yes, fixed that works now.

Comment: Since you already loaded the file into memory, use it: `influxProps.load(new StringReader(result))` --- Also, remember to close the `inputStream`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read stream twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501237/read-stream-twice)