# How to Run New Scanner Sucessfully

Tags: java

Trying to get the scanner to start from the beginning but receiving an error code while doing so. The code currently is only supposed to make sure the input does not have more than nine integers, otherwise it will output "Too many number", and I am trying to make in put the integers into the array "v".

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class LabProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      int length;
      int i;
      boolean tm = false;
      for(i = 0; scnr.hasNextInt(); i++){
         int x = scnr.nextInt();
         if(i > 9){
            tm = true;
            System.out.print("Too many numbers");
            break;
         }
        
      }
     if(!tm){
         int[] v = new int[i];
         Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
         for(i = 0; i < v.length; i++){
            v[i] = scnr.nextInt();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read input stream twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501237/read-input-stream-twice)

Comment: Mastering Scanner is such a waste of time. If you go on to be a professional, the chances that you ever need to use this are minimal. And in terms of input validation, HTML 5's input.pattern (and other attributes for number fields, etc) are the state of the art and (IMO) much more useful to learn.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve multiple areas in your code. Your main challenge is not actually to reset the scanner but rather ensure right acceptance of data. If the threshold exceeds then the data must not be recorded.

You can create an array and right away start filling it up. Once it crosses the threshold of 9 numbers you must just check if there are still any more numbers left. If there are still more incoming numbers then you can give that error message and reset your filled out array.

*FYR Code:*

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CorrectLabProgram {
    private final static int SIZE = 9;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] v = new int[SIZE];
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 9 && scan.hasNext()) {
            v[i] = scan.nextInt();
            i++;
        }
        if (scan.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("Too many numbers");
            // You can reset your array here either way
            Arrays.fill(v, 0);
            v = null;
        }
    }
}
```

I also added some comments to your original code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        int length; // Unused variable
        int i;
        boolean tm = false;
        for(i = 0; scnr.hasNextInt(); i++){
            int x = scnr.nextInt();  // Unused variable
            if(i > 9){
                tm = true;
                System.out.print("Too many numbers");
                break;
            }

        }
        if(!tm){
            int[] v = new int[i]; // This can create size 10 array which would be undesirable
            Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in); // Unused variable
            for(i = 0; i < v.length; i++){
                v[i] = scnr.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }
}
```