# Corrupting Input Stream while validating it make it 0 byte during storing in s3

Tags: java, xml, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, quarkus

We have a application in which we are sending file of content type: form-data then we are retrieving it, we mapped it to a custom class as Input Stream

```
public class Request{
   InputStream stream;
   public InputStream getStream() {
       return stream;
   }

   public void setStream(InputStream stream) {
       this.stream= stream;
   }
}
```

Now we serve this as dto.
And in the second class we have a method in which we are putting it into s3 an inside this method we call another method to validate the content of this file.

```
public Response save(Request dto){
   validateFile(dto.getStream());
    // save file in s3 by converting it into readingAllBytes for input stream
}

public void validateFile(InputStream dto){
   // For this i can't put the code.
   // In here we are have a code to validate the xml file content using the DocuemtnBuilder Factory
// can follow this https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2Ftutorial%2F/jaxp/dom/validating.html
}
```

Now when i saw the file in s3 there is file created but no data inside.
This issue arises when we add the validateFile method. Previously it was working fine.

Comment: Without code it's pretty hard to tell. But it's possible that you're not closing properly the input stream after you processed it in your `validateFile` method ? Do you use a *try with resource* or a classic *try catch finally* ?

Comment: I am closing it. I use the try catch finally.

Comment: Maybe reseting the stream after processing it will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21434748/11648839

Comment: You've mentioned, _"...This issue arises when we add the validateFile method. Previously it was working fine. ..."_.  Can you provide the code you were using previously?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot read multiple times from an `InptutStream`.

As I see, it tries to save the file reading the same InputStream that was passed to `validateFile(dto.getStream());`

Within `validateFile(...)` it uses XML schema validation, which requires to read the InputStream. So, when it returns from `validateFile(...)`, input stream is already closed.

So basically, `validateFile(...)` should return a copy of same 'InputStream', and use it to save in S3.

Something like the following;

```
public Response save(Request dto){
   InputStream validatedInputStream = validateFile(dto.getStream());
   saveToS3(validatedInputStream);
}
```

Assuming `validateFile(...)` returns a new InputStream (it could be a copy of the origninal InputStream from the `Request.stream` or a new InputStream generated as part of the validation process).