# Splitting an InputStream into two buffered InputStreams

Tags: kotlin

I have a DicomInputStream. It represents data being sent over the wire from an ultrasound machine. I want to send that data to two different API's that each take an InputStream as their argument (i.e. they consume those bytes). I do not want to load the ENTIRE files into memory (some of them are 300mb+ each), but instead want to buffer them (perhaps into an intermediary stream), then have each output consume them.

Does anyone have any recommended strategies?

I've tried using the functions in [Read input stream twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501237/read-input-stream-twice), but ran into issues.

In particular the SplittableInputStream in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30262036/145567 was promising. But it just hangs as the buffer grows too large. It works for smallish files.

Here is my code right now (after many previous different attempts):

```
val in = new PipedInputStream()
val tee = new TeeInputStream(dicomInputStream, new PipedOutputStream(in))

// Read the other inputstream on a different thread
val f1 = Future {
  println("inside f1")
  storageApiClient.forwardInstance(in, calledAet, "123", instanceUID)
}

// Read tee on same thread. 
healthcareApiClient.stowRs(tee, calledAet)

Await.result(f1, Duration.Inf)
```

With this code, the future never resolves

Comment: What issues? https://stackoverflow.com/a/55890953/40342 for example seems like a very thorough implementation of what you want. Note that in general, if the two readers are in some way dependent on each other you might end up needing an arbitrarily large buffer to not block one of them. If blocking one of them until the other continues reading is fine, then you don't need a (large) buffer.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Yep, totally get that in order to keep a smallish buffer the consumers will block each other. I just cannot figure it out

Answer (score 2):

I've finally solved it.

```
val pipedOut01 = new PipedOutputStream();
val p1 = new PipedInputStream()
pipedOut01.connect(p1)
val tee = new TeeInputStream(dicomInputStream, pipedOut01, true);

val executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool()

val f2 = executor.submit(new Runnable {
  override def run(): Unit = {
    println("Started reading p1")
    storageApiClient.forwardInstance(
      p1,
      calledAet,
      "123",
      instanceUID,
    )
  }
})
```